# interface declaration in PHP - why do declarations get mixed?

Tags: php, interface, namespaces

I'm tring to declare interfaces for my classes like this:

```
namespace Helpers\Interfaces {
    interface Cache {
        public static function getInstance($profile = null);
    }
}
```

And then I apply them like this:

```
namespace Helpers {
    class Cache implements Interfaces\Cache {
        public static function getInstance($profile = null) {
            /* ... */
        }
    }
}
```

So far, so good (apparently, at least). The problem I have is NetBeans gives me an error stating my class is not abstract and doesn't implement a certain method.

The method belongs to an object I created to gather the configuration parameters needed to operate certain methods without providing specific configuration options depending on the object (like host, port, API key, etc.).

This method is, in this example, called as `\Configuration\Helpers\Cache::getConfiguration($profile);`

The conflicting declaration comes from this interface:

```
namespace Configuration\Helpers\Interfaces {
    interface Cache {
        public static function getConfiguration($profile = null);
    }
}
```

Which is applied as follows:

```
namespace Configuration\Helpers {
    class Cache implements Interfaces\Cache {
        public static function getConfiguration($profile = null) {
            /* ... */
        }
    }
}
```

It's effectively mixing the interfaces, although they're namespaced!
Something I would like to note is both the interface and the class declaration implementing such interface are always in the same file, one file per object.

PHP version is 7.0.13 on NetBeans 8.2.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Your interfaces and classes are in different namespaces. You may need to add a use statement to your class. For example you can add: use Helpers\Interfaces as Interfaces. This line can go above the class definition: class Cache implements Interfaces\Cache.

See also: http://php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.definitionmultiple.php

Comment: I'll give it a try. Thanks for the hint :)

Comment: No, it doesn't make the error notice dissapear. I, however, suspect it's related to NetBeans rather than my coding style, as I don't have any warning or error while executing my code, it's just NetBeans complaining about the declaration...